# Incompatible types ao tentar iniciar uma classe com o valor do "switch" de outra Java

Tags: java, parâmetros, enums

Tenho o seguinte:

```
public class Bullet {
    public enum Direcao { UP,DOWN,LEFT,RIGHT };
    // Posição do tiro em pixels.
    private int x,y;
     // Direção do tiro.
    private Direcao direção;
    // Este tiro está ativo?
    private boolean estáAtivo;
    // Tamanho do tiro em pixels.
    private int iw,ih;
    // Imagem do tiro.
    private Image icon;
    // área do painel do jogo (para controlar movimento).
    private Dimension area;

    // Construtor, inicializa atributos, cria a bala.
    public Bullet(Dimension a,Direcao dir, int x,int y){
        area = a;
        icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/gamejava.Sprites/bullet.png")).getImage();
        iw = icon.getWidth(null);
        ih = icon.getHeight(null);
        // x e y passados direto como argumentos
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        direção = dir;
        estáAtivo = true;
    }

    // Método que movimenta a bala.
    public void move(){
        if (!estáAtivo) return;
        switch(direção){
            case LEFT:
                {
                    x -= 3; if (x < 0) estáAtivo = false; break;
                }
            case RIGHT:
                {
                    x += 3; if (x > area.width) estáAtivo = false; break;
                }
            case UP:
                {
                    y -= 3; if (y < 0) estáAtivo = false; break;
                }
            case DOWN:
                {
                    y += 3; if (y > area.height-100) estáAtivo = false; break;
                }
        } 
    }
```

e também:

```
public class Bomb {
    public enum Direcao { UP,DOWN,LEFT,RIGHT };
    // Posição da bomba em pixels.
    private int x,y;
    // Esta bomba está ativa?
    private boolean estáAtivo;
    // Tamanho da bomba em pixels.
    private int iw,ih;
    // Imagem da bomba.
    private Image icon;
    // área do painel do jogo (para controlar movimento).
    private Dimension area;
    // Construtor, inicializa atributos, cria a bomba.

    public Bomb(Dimension a,int x,int y){
        area = a;
        icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/gamejava.Sprites/bomb.png")).getImage();
        iw = icon.getWidth(null);
        ih = icon.getHeight(null);
        // x e y passadas diretamente como parâmetros
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        estáAtivo = true;
    }

    // Método que movimenta o shooter, verificando se está na área válida.
    public void move(Direcao dir){
        if (dir == null) return;
        switch(dir){
            case LEFT:
                { x--; 
                if (x < iw/2) x = iw/2; 
                break; }
            case RIGHT:
                { x++; if (x > area.width-iw/2) x = area.width-iw/2; break; }
            case UP:
                { y--; if (y < area.height-100+ih/2) y = area.height-100+ih/2; break; }
            case DOWN:
                { y++; if (y > area.height-ih/2) y = area.height-ih/2; break; }
        }
    }
    // Método que movimenta a bomba.
    public void move(){
        if (!estáAtivo) return;
        y = y-3;
        if (y <= 0) estáAtivo = false;
    }
    // Método que desenha a bomba em um contexto gráfico.
    public void draw(Graphics g){
        if (estáAtivo) g.drawImage(icon,x-iw/2,y-ih/2,null);
    }
    // Precisamos saber se esta bomba está ativa!
    public boolean estáAtivo() {
        return estáAtivo; 
    }
    // Verificamos se a bomba está perto de um Invader
    public boolean acertouEm(Invader i){
        int ox = i.getX(); int oy = i.getY();
        return (Math.sqrt((x-ox)*(x-ox)+(y-oy)*(y-oy)) < 25);
    }

    // Explodimos a bomba (retornando bullets).
    public ArrayList<Bullet> explode(){
        ArrayList<Bullet> novasBalas = new ArrayList<Bullet>(4);
        novasBalas.add(new Bullet(area, Direcao.LEFT, x, y));
        novasBalas.add(new Bullet(area, Direcao.RIGHT, x, y));
        novasBalas.add(new Bullet(area, Direcao.UP, x, y));
        novasBalas.add(new Bullet(area, Direcao.DOWN, x, y));
        estáAtivo = false;
        return novasBalas;
    }
}
```

Duas classes separadas, `Bullet` e `Bomb`. Na classe Bomb, o método explode está mostrando o seguinte erro no meu NetBeans:

[image: IDE mostrando o erro]

Como eu passo aquele parâmetro de `Direcao` para a outra classe? Ali diz que está incompatível.

Comment: o que ocorre é que o enum Direcao da classe Bullet e da classe Bomb são embora parecidos, diferentes devido a classe, em termos de responsabilidade unica, o ideal seria que você fizesse esse enum numa classe separada

Comment: Vou testar! Não sabia dessa do enum

Comment: Consegui, muito obrigado, a solução foi criar uma classe para Direcao mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mudando a ordem dos argumentos resolverá:

```
novasBalas.add(new Bullet(area, x, y, Direcao.LEFT));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/Enum.java).

Note que a direção é o último parâmetro no construtor da classe `Bullet`, portanto ele o argumento com este valor deve aparecer por último, e não em segundo como está no seu exemplo. Obviamente precisa fazer nos 4.

Comment: Corrigi a ordem e persiste o problema. Acho que foi só bobeira minha na hora de colar aqui, a ordem das coisas, mas já resolvi e o problema é o mesmo.

Comment: Arrumei na pergunta tal qual fiz no código

Comment: Experimenta ter essa `Enum` fora das classes, não faz sentido ter ela dentro, se faz parte da API em mais de uma classe é muito errado estar internalizada. Ela deve ser pública mesmo. De qualquer forma eu não confio mais no que está postando, afinal já postou uma coisa e dizia outra., o que falar pode estar certo ou pode ser só uma versão do que de fato ocorre.

Comment: Vou testar isso Maniero. Desculpa, não entendi, estou sendo pouco confiável? Peso perdão então, apenas fiz a correção que você sugeriu.